# Scaling on constraints and variables for solving NLP problems, using CONOPT4

Tags: solver, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

I am currently using CONOPT4 solver to solve nonlinear programming problem.The nonlinearity is in the form of z=x*y and z=x/y, all variables are continuous. I specify some scaling factors and solving performance improves a lot. However, when I further refine some scaling factors, to project the value into the range from 0.01 to 100. The solving time becomes longer, which is really weird. I cannot provide my code here and I know it's impossible to give specific reason without the code. Could you talk about your experience on generally tuning the scaling factors when using CONOPT sovler. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would **always** rewrite `z=x/y` as `z*y=x`.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Reformulation is a good idea. What I have here is: Z1 = x11*y11 + x12*y12 + ..... and Z2 = x21/y21 + x22/y22+..... I am thinking about giving intermediate variables, especially with x21=y21*c21. In theory, performance would be better.And I will test it. I am going through the solver manual, but still have no clue about scaling.

Comment: Scaling is very important. But note that (1) Conopt does automatic scaling, (2) better bounds and (3) better initial point are also critically important.